# Styling elements of a HTML Website

Tags: html, css

**Question:**

How do I style different elements of a HTML website properly? I've looked all over the internet and read books but am still sort of struggling.

**Issue:**

My problem is that I have a main heading, which is like the main "title" for my website which displays the website name, but to the left of my heading, I want to style a vertical navigation bar which will be in-line with my heading. Yet I am having trouble styling the navbar and heading to work next to each other, rather than one of them being on top of the other.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnkuetuy/)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
<head>
  <title>CSGOWin | Win Big!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Jackpot.html">Jackpot</a></li>
    <li><a href="Jackpot.html">Coinflip</a></li>
    <li><a href="News.html">Giveaways</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a><li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1>CSGO Win</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-image: url(bgimg.jpg);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: 100%;
}
h1 {
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
background-color: #FFA500;
border-style: solid;
border-radius: 25px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 350px;
margin-right: 350px;
padding-top: 1%;
padding-bottom: 1%;
font-size: 45px;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-right: 85%;
margin-top: 50px;
background-color: #FFA500;
}
li a {
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
display: block;
}
.navbar{
}
```

Finally, I am very new to stack overflow, so I apologise if my question is not fully detailed. I will answer questions if there are any. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to set this up... one is to set your .navbar class and ul class to "display: inline-block".  Another way is to use floats (slightly more difficult).  Possibly the best way, especially if you want your menu to stay fixed, is to use position: absolute or position: fixed on your .navbar class.  I'd research those 3 options and see what fits your page setup best.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code, so picking up one definitive answer and saying "This is how you solve it", won't help. It's definitely worth looking up on how positioning specific elements work - and what you would like them to do in certain situations. Look at the `position:` and  `float:` for positioning, and read into `margin:` to see where you're making your mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comment you can use `float: left` see this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpWzeK?editors=1100. Another way to do it is by using flex.

Comment: Thanks for this. Quick question though; How come the contents inside of the border have been muddled up? Like the text has been placed on multiple lines and the background color is off.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want that to look, but you can play with the styling of the ul inside navbar. For example you can set a fixed width. I've updated the pen

Answer (score 0):

you can add class or id attributes to certain html tags and then in your stylesheet  reference that class or id

->.navbar{
}
that references any tag with "navbar" class will get the style in that block

->#thisIsAnID{
}
that references any tag with the id " thisIsAnID" id 
so . is used for classes

## is used for ids